# Graphql Field doesn't exist on type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, graphql

After skimming through the docs of Graphql I've started to implement it on a toy rails/reactJS project. The projects allows an user to sign in through devise then access a dummy /artist route that displays a list of artists. Everything seems to work fine until I try to consume api data with GraphQL from the react app to get artists and display them.

On the server side, I have a **graphql_controller.rb** such as:

```
class GraphqlController < ApiController
  rescue_from Errors::Unauthorized do |exception|
    render json: {errors: ['Unauthorized.']}, status: :unauthorized
  end

  def index
    result = Schema.execute params[:query], variables: params[:variables], context: context
    render json: result, status: result['errors'] ? 422 : 200
  end

private

  def context
    token, options = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.token_and_options request
    {
      ip_address: request.remote_ip
    }
  end
end
```

Then, following to my model logic, I have set up graphql under graph/ with the following files:

**graph/queries/artist_query.rb**

```
ArtistQuery = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'ArtistQuery'
  description 'The query root for this schema'

  field :artists, types[Types::ArtistType] do
    resolve(->(_, _, _) {
      Artist.all
    })
  end
end
```

**types/artist_type.rb**

```
Types::ArtistType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
  name 'Artist'
  description 'A single artist.'

  field :id, !types.ID
  field :name, types.String
  field :description, types.String
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
Schema = GraphQL::Schema.define do
  query ArtistQuery
end
```

On the client side, for the sake of keeping things organized, I use 3 files to render this artist list:

First, **ArtistSchema.js**

```
import { gql } from 'react-apollo';

const artistListQuery = gql`
    {
        query {
            artists {
                id
                name
                description     
            }
        }
    }
`;

export default artistListQuery;
```

Then, an **`Artist.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Artist extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{this.props.index + 1}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
                <td>{this.props.data.description} min</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

export default Artist;
```

And finally, wrapping these two together in a larger layout: **Artists.jsx**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {graphql} from 'react-apollo';
import Artist from './Artist';
import artistListQuery from './ArtistSchema';

class Artists extends Component {
    render() {
        if(this.props.data.loading) {
            return (<p>Loading</p>)
        } else {

            console.log(this.props.data)
            const ArtistsItems = this.props.data.artists.map((data,i) => {
                return (<Artist key={i} index={i} data={data}></Artist>);
            });
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Artists</h1>
                    <table className="table table-striped table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        { ArtistsItems }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            );
        }

    }
}

export default graphql(artistListQuery)(Artists);
```

What happens when this code is executed:

On server-side (sorry for the unformatted output, but it displays like this in console):

```
Processing by GraphqlController#index as */*
18:49:46 api.1  |   Parameters: {"query"=>"{\n  query {\n    artists {\n      id\n      name\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n", "operationName"=>nil, "graphql"=>{"query"=>"{\n  query {\n    artists {\n      id\n      name\n      description\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n", "operationName"=>nil}}
```

Followed by the error:

```
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 36ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

On the client side, if I monitor Network > Response for graphql, I (of course) receive a 422 error code and the following error message:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Field 'query' doesn't exist on type 'ArtistQuery'","locations":[{"line":2,"column":3}],"fields":["query","query"]}]}
```

I assume my query is not done correctly. I have been trying various queries formats (from docs or gists examples) but I cannot end finding a correct way to get back my artist data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I don't think this is the issue for this particular case, but I was getting this error and it turned out to be due to a simple syntax error. **Query attributes need to be in camelCase format, not under_score format.** Maybe this will help someone else that lands here when searching for this error like I did.

Comment: Ooof I spent an hour or more around not understanding why my 2nd returned field worked... it was this. Doh. Thanks

Comment: Ugggggggh this was killing me for over an hour. Thank you so much for posting this!

Comment: this is da....m right!!!!! thx

Comment: I owe you many internet points for this. Thank you for dispelling my ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was that I had a structure like this:

```
module Types
  class SomeType < Types::BaseObject
    field :comparator,
          Types::ComparatorType
    field :options,
          [Types::OptionType]
  end
end
```

BUT in the query I had other nested structure called **data** that I forgot about:

```
mutation {
  myMutation(
    ...  
  ) {
    someType {
      comparator {
        ...
      }
      data {
        options {
           ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So after changing `SomeType` class to add that missing key solved my issue. So now it look like this:

```
module Types
  class SomeType < Types::BaseObject
    field :comparator,
          Types::ComparatorType
    field :data,
          Types::DataType
  end
end

# New file
module Types
  class DataType < Types::BaseObject
    field :options,
          [Types::OptionType]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The GQL query you sent is malformed, it is asking for the `query` field of `Query` root object. Use this instead:

```
const artistListQuery = gql`
    query UseTheNameYouWantHere {
        artists {
            id
            name
            description     
        }
    }
`;
```

BTW, you can add `graphiql` gem (https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphiql-rails) to have a playground with your GraphQL API.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but I tried that before, doing what you advice me results in an error on the client side like: 
`apollo.umd.js:1409 Uncaught Error: Encountered a sub-selection on the query, but the store doesn't have an object reference. This should never happen during normal use unless you have custom code that is directly manipulating the store; please file an issue.`

The server doesnt even get the request when I use the query code you provided.

Concerning the graphiql client provided by the game I dont have access to it because my app is an api without views.

Answer (score 0):

All right, the problem is not in the code itself. I changed the query to the one you adviced and updated the name artists to something else on both client and server side. 
It seems like apollo-rails is caching previous api calls, even if they failed, that why I was always getting the same error. I still have to figure out how to clean this cache. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in **RSpec**, but not in a real call, i.e. Postman, for the same query. The solution was to change the query in spec from

```
<<~QUERY
  query users {
    posts {
      ...
    }
  }
QUERY
```

to

```
<<~QUERY
  query users {
    users {
      posts {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
QUERY
```

However in other specs, the first approach was working with similarly looking mutation, so I am not sure what was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a newer API endpoint URL version.

Example Request URL: https://shopify-graphiql-app.shopifycloud.com/api/*2022-01*/graphql

Comment: page doesnt exist, even without the asterisks

Answer (score 0):

If you are still experiencing the issue, and you have arleady **double checked** that:

1. You are making a GraphQL query using camel case. E.g. `visitCount` instead of `visit_count`
2. You have a valid field and it is spelled correctly.

```rb
field :visit_count, Integer, :null => false, :description => "The sum of.."
```

3. The field is in the correct type.

E.g. If you are writing a query for:

```
{
  user {
    nodes {
      blogs {
        name
        visitCount
      }
    }
  }
}
```

your `visit_count` field should be in the `BlogType`.

If you are still experiencing this issue:

### Check if you have an: `Looking up hash key` Error

It may look like:

```html
Failed to implement Blog.visitCount, tried:

- `Types::BlogType#visit_count`, which did not exist
- `AppGraphql#visit_count`, which did not exist
- Looking up hash key `:visit_count` or `"visit_count"` on `#<AppGraphql:0x00007f8394982e88>`, but it wasn't a Hash.

To implement this field, define one of the methods above (and check for typos)
```

If this is the case, it's looking up a key for `visit_count` instead of `visitCount`. We need to update the field to include a `hash_key`.

#### ❌ Before:

```rb
field :visit_count, Integer, :null => false
```

#### ✅ After:

```rb
field :visit_count, Integer, :null => false, :hash_key => :visitCount
```