# Consuming GraphQL underscore with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

I'm using `graphql-client` in Ruby on Rails to use monday's api so the problem is that in the api the names are with underscore, when I try to query something

```
query {
  items (limit: 50) {
    column_values {
       id
       value
     }
  }
}
```

I got an error like this `GraphQL::Client::ValidationError (Field 'column_values' doesn't exist on type 'Item')`, after read some websites (e.g [Graphql Field doesn't exist on type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595547/graphql-field-doesnt-exist-on-type)) it says that you have to change the underscore to camelCase. So I did it

```
query {
  items (limit: 50) {
     columnValues {
       id
       value
     }
  }
}
```

And I didn't get the error from ruby but after sent the query the response from the server (monday api) was the same but with the camelcase `Field 'columnValues' doesn't exist on type 'Item'`.

After read other websites seems like under_score and camelCase is a common issue with GraphQL.

Comment: query tested in monday's playground? if it works then create an issue on graphql-client github - underscored names are valid in graphql specs

Comment: Yes I did test the query in monday's playground and it works just fine with the under_score, if I change to camelCase doesn't work. The problem is when I parse `Query = SWAPI::Client.parse`in ruby the doesn't let me continue, only if I use camelCase but it will have a conflict with monday's api. I saw in github an issue similar https://github.com/github/graphql-client/issues/212 from last year open with no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby but IMHO this issue is rather from `graphql-ruby`, source of `StaticValidation`.

This lib looks like intended more for server/backend usage. It has some internals to convert names, arguments etc. for later/internal usage (resolvers) with camel cased fields. Explore some related [threads](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20snake). As server probably it's configurable (autocamelize etc.).

### Concerns

Both usage (camel and snake) gives the same error for field (not existing on type). IMHO you can/should:

- check 'Item' type - dump loaded schema;

If it is properly defined:

- fork this project (`graphql-client`) and disable some validation rules (f.e. GraphQL::StaticValidation::FieldsAreDefinedOnType) by excluding them [here](https://github.com/github/graphql-client/blob/2bbe6a5f360521e31d5be3397ddef7ca0205585c/lib/graphql/client.rb#L183) (like 2 already excluded).
- you can disable all validation (comment out lines 190-197)

I hope you should be able to use this query after that.